# Dataframe groupby - list of values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a following dataframe:

```
driver_id                           status  dttm
9f8f9bf3ee8f4874873288c246bd2d05    free    2018-02-04 00:19
9f8f9bf3ee8f4874873288c246bd2d05    busy    2018-02-04 01:03
8f174ffd446c456eaf3cca0915d0368d    free    2018-02-03 15:43
8f174ffd446c456eaf3cca0915d0368d    enroute 2018-02-03 17:02
```

3 columns : driver_id, status, dttm

What I need to do is to group by driver id and make list of all statuses with their respective dttm values into new column called `'driver_info'`:

```
driver_id                           driver_info
9f8f9bf3ee8f4874873288c246bd2d05    [("free", 2018-02-04 00:19), ("busy", 2018-02-04 01:03)]
8f174ffd446c456eaf3cca0915d0368d    [("free", 2018-02-03 15:43), ("enroute", 2018-02-03 17:02) ...]
```

How do I do that in python 3?

I tried

```py
dfg = df.groupby("driver_id").apply(lambda x: pd.concat((x["status"], x["dttm"])))
```

but the result differs from what I expect it to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `list` and `zip` for list of tuples:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('driver_id')
         .apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['status'], x['dttm'])))
         .reset_index(name='driver_info'))
print (df1)
                          driver_id  \
0  8f174ffd446c456eaf3cca0915d0368d   
1  9f8f9bf3ee8f4874873288c246bd2d05   

                                         driver_info  
0  [(free, 2018-02-03 15:43), (enroute, 2018-02-0...  
1  [(free, 2018-02-04 00:19), (busy, 2018-02-04 0...
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Just the result I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try:  using zip and apply(list)

```
df['driver_info'] = list(zip(df['status'], df['dttm']))
df = df.groupby('driver_id')['driver_info'].apply(list)
```